# RoR - Haml::SyntaxError Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %div and nested within it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error, haml

What is wrong with this code? Every my change give me

> Haml::SyntaxError
>
> Illegal nesting: content can't be both given on the same line as %div
>   and nested within it.

```
    .container
        .navbar-brand= link_to "Recipe Box", root_path
            %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
                %li= link_to "New Recipe", new_recipe_path
                %li= link_to "Sign Out", root_path
```

Help me, please, I'm new in **RoR**. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The error message tells you _exactly_ what's wrong.

Comment: You can have content either on the same line with `.navbar-brand` or nested in it. Not both.

Comment: For  Sergio Tulentsev                                                                                    Yes, I read it. But I tried to change the line which was in red (%ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right ) and nothing helped. Do you think if I can't fix it I can't asked about it - if you won't help - you just don't and thats all. I don't need your comment with my error text copied.

Comment: If you want to have a career in programming, you will need to improve your reading comprehension. Not an insult or anything, but a fact of life.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your advice. Sorry for that comment, it's because I spent a lot of time for that and can't fixed

Answer (score 1):

```
.container
    .navbar-brand
        = link_to "Recipe Box", root_path
        %ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
            %li= link_to "New Recipe", new_recipe_path
            %li= link_to "Sign Out", root_path
```